# I have a button that im trying to click with selenium however there are more css selectors than buttons

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click on the 'details' button on https://www.rogers.com/web/totes/wireless/choose-phone. However it seems as though I cant click it. The page seems to be dynamic and so the link does not change.

I have tried selecting the button by link but only to realise it stays on the same link regardless if that button is click. There are 66 elements under the 'details' button when there should only be 32. Therefore when I try selecting any from that list of elements, none work.

```
phoneDetailsPath = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select-font.ng-scope')))
phoneDetailsPath[num].click()
```

I am hoping to be able to store all the 'details' paths into a list and click the button at that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps you can use selector

```
[ng-click*=gotoDeviceConfigure]
```

Automationists won't like using javascript but you can execute click as follows:

```
#first item
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("[ng-click*=gotoDeviceConfigure]").click();')

# using indices
driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("[ng-click*=gotoDeviceConfigure]")[1].click();')
```

However, you need to scroll later elements into view and you need to handle dimissing pop-ups about being signed up unless already logged in (I guess).

Comment: I appreciate your help. These dynamic pages do not. Make it easy to scrape

Comment: @QHarr You have wrote a lot of helpful answers using `EC` why suddenly jumping straight into `execute_script()`

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB ! I was just going to bed and didn't have time to spend on extensive testing. I honestly thought someone else would come up with something better in terms of test automation (and probably still will). This was more a back up  in for OP - like a plan B.

Comment: do you guys think there is anyway to select buttons with 'details' only?